# Геоточки в plotly

Tags: plotly, mapbox, geo

Есть данные магазинов с широтой и долготой. Вот так строю геокарту с точками

`fig = px.scatter_mapbox(sellers_geo, lat="geolocation_lat", lon="geolocation_lng", color="seller_city",hover_name='seller_city', color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.RdBu, size_max=15, zoom=7, mapbox_style="open-street-map") fig.show()`

Но есть магазины с одинаковыми широтой и долготой(то есть, находятся в одном месте).И если магазины находятся в одном месте, то необходимо в данной точке на карте отметить их количество. Как это можно добавить?

Answer (score 0):

посчитайте количество одинаковых совпадений и нанесите их на карту с помощью
fig.add_annotation, подробнее [в официальной документации с примерами](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/)